# What is the difference between Reader Account and Consumer Account

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can anyone please get me out of confusion in scope of Reader Account and Consumer Account. I was in assumption that Reader account is created by provider to help consumer account. But here in official diagram Consumer Account is having direct access on DB(left) of Provider Account [link](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-sharing-reader-create.html)   [image]

Answer (score 3):

> The main difference is that you are responsible for the cost of the warehouse, managing users, and roles of a reader account.  For a consumer account you are not responsible for any of that.

#### As an example:

You have your Snowflake account and you need to share data with two of your vendors (A & B). Vendor A has their own Snowflake account; Vendor B *doesn't* have their own Snowflake account.

First you setup a data *SHARE* object so that both vendors can access the data **without logging into your account.**

The ***Provider Account*** is you.  You are providing them with data.

The ***Consumer Account*** is Vendor A.  You will add their Snowflake account to the *SHARE* object to provide them data to their Snowflake account, and they will use their warehouses to query the data.

The ***Reader Account*** is Vendor B.  Since Vendor B doesn't have a Snowflake account, you will create a *MANAGED ACCOUNT* object.  This will supply you with a Snowflake account name and URL that you can give to Vendor B.  You must then add the account name to the *SHARE* you created in the beginning.  Next you must login to the reader account as the admin, create a database from the share, create users, roles, and at least one warehouse to use.  When Vendor B logins into that managed account URL they will only be able to see data in the database from the share (same as Vendor A).

Comment: So Consumer can be both 'Bill Payer' and 'NonBill Payer' at the same time ? Reader Account will always be 'Non Bill Payer' ... ? is this correct..?

Comment: A reader account is DB connection you give to someone else, but you pay the bill. And you share your data into that account (and manage it).. But they are not logging into your account, so cannot DOS you etc etc. But that can smash your bill if you do not setup limits. A consumer account is where you share you data to someone else account, so they can read your data (like the reader) and they pay for all of their usage, because it's their account. @PIG